# Database structure for "customer" table having many orders per customer and many items per order

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a database where each customer has several orders(new orders daily) and each order has several items. I had planned creating a table of customers and creating a table per order and populating this table with an "items" table. I think this approach is too complicated and cumbersome since the number of orders can reach the thousands, I don't think having thousands of tables is maintainable. What do you think would be an appropriate structure for this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is a noobish question, I am learning to program. And this is my first ever attempt at database design.

Comment: If you're a beginner you should probably first try to set up an [ERM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). Everything else should just be derived from that.

Comment: Think of tables as where you store similar types of things, Orders belong in one table because the same kinds of information will be kept about each one. If ever you find yourself thinking you'd have multiple tables with the same structure, you should stop and think about your design.   There are plenty of good resources and samples, look for 'sample order database' or 'sample db schema'.

Comment: @GoatCO Thanks for the tip on what not to do! Yes, I really thought the idea of having a table per order was pretty awful, but it was one of the best ideas that popped into my mind.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need four tables, something like this:

[image: Possible Simplified Database Model]

### Customers

Contains a list of customers. One row per Customer. Would contain all the customer's information - their contact details, etc...

### Orders

Contains a list of orders. One row per order. Each order is placed by a customer and has a `Customer_ID` - which can be used to link back to the customer record. Might also store the delivery address, if different from the customers address from their record - or store addresses in separate tables.

### OrderItems

Contains a list of order items. One row for each item on an order - so each Order can generate multiple rows in this table. Each item ordered is a product from your inventory, so each row has a product_id, which links to the products table.

### Products

Contains a list of products. One row per product. Similar to the customers table, but for products - contains all the product details.

Here's the SQL code that you could use to create this structure - it will create a database for itself called `mydb`:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Customers` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `PhoneNo` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Orders`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Orders` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `customer_id` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Order_1_idx` (`customer_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Customers` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Products`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Products` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Description` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`OrderItems`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`OrderItems` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Order_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_OrderItem_1_idx` (`Order_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_OrderItem_2_idx` (`Product_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_OrderItem_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Order_ID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Orders` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_OrderItem_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Products` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `mydb` ;
```

Comment: @HartCO Wouldn't that be the same thing as the Product table in the answer?

Comment: May I ask what tool was used to visualise this?

Comment: @Robin It's the standard thing that comes with mysql, not sure what it's called. It's an optional download, but available from the same place.

Comment: I'm working on the same thing, what if I wanted to add some tables that tracked payments for these orders?

Comment: @bteague To add a payments table would just be more of the same. A table called `payments`, with an `ID`, a `customer_id`, and an `order_id` (if you want to tie a payment to an order), an `amount` - and any other information you want to collect about the payment.

Comment: Instead of Order and OrderItem table , we can mantain order_id customer_id item_id in the same table lets call it order table in that way we can avoid orderitem table , can u please let me know is it a right or wrong

Comment: This is called Denormalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization - it can be a reasonable thing to do if you have specific reasons for doing it. Otherwise, a normalized database structure, as described in my answer, is the right thing to do in most cases.

Comment: Would just like to add that `Order` is a reserved word.  So if anyone decides to borrow this and tries to interact with the table, they need to use back ticks otherwise mysql will return an error.  For example `desc Order` will fail, but `desc \`Order\`` won't.

Comment: One question (I don't know much about Relational database): If we have to search orders of a particular customer. Do we have to scan entire orders table for that?

Comment: No, the order table has an index on customer_id, so doing "select * from orders where customer_id = 123" will perform an index scan and only read rows from the orders table where the customer_id on the row matches. Index scans are very fast and efficient.

Comment: @dan I updated the table names to plural, so `Order` is now `Orders`, so no longer a reserved word.

Answer (score 9):

There's no sense in creating a table per order. Don't do that. It's not practical, not maintainable. You won't be able to normally query your data. For starters all you need just  four tables like this

- customers
- orders
- order_items
- products (or items)

Here is oversimplified **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ed32/3)** demo

Comment: One question (I don't know much about Relational database): If we have to search orders of a particular customer. Do we have to scan entire orders table for that?

Comment: You don't if you have an index on the customer column in the orders table.

Comment: Gotcha. Just got to know about index.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have something like a customer table along with orders and items tables. The primary key of customer is the foreign key of order. Items will then have a foreign key that matches the order it was placed on.

3 tables should be fine