# Build normalised MSSQL dB from CSV files in Python + Pandas + sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, csv

I am learning by doing - Python, Pandas, SQL & Deep Learning. I want to build a database with data for a deep learning experiment (with Keras and Tensorflow). The source data is ~10GB (total) of forex timestamped bid/ask data in 8 CSV files with source information encoded as three 3-4 char strings for categories Contributor, Region and City.

I can connect to my (empty) MSSQL database via pyodbc and sqlAlchemy; I can read my CSV files into dataframes; I can create a simple table in the dB and even create one from a simple dataframe; I can convert the date and time fields into the milliseconds since epoch I want. (And, FWIW, I already have already implemented a working toy LSTM model to adapt to the price data, and I also have some analytical functions I wrote and compiled in Mathematica; I'll either call the C from Python or get Mathematica to work directly on the database.)

The issue is putting the CSV data into the database. Since there are only a dozen or so different sources in each category I believe I should put Contributor etc. into separate tables with e.g Contributor_ID as ints (?) so that data is stored compactly and e.g. SELECT... WHERE Region = "SHRUBBERY" are efficient. (AFAICT I definitely shouldn't use enums because I may get more sources & categories later).

**My question is** - assuming the aforementioned high level of ignorance! - how can/should I a) create the tables and relationships using python and then b) populate those tables?

Optional extra: to save space, the CSV files omit the Region and City where the row values are the same as those for the row above - reading the CSVs to collect just the source information (which takes about 50s for each category) I know how to deduplicate and dropna, but when I want to populate the dB, how can I most efficiently replace the na's with the values from the previous row? A simple For loop would do it, but is there e.g. some way to "propagate" the last "real" value in a column to replace the na using pandas?

CSV example:

```
Date    Time    Bid Price   Ask Price   Contributor Region  City
04/02/2017  00:00.1 1.00266 1.00282 DCFX    ASI AKL
04/02/2017  00:00.1 1.00263 1.0028  DCFX        
04/02/2017  00:00.2 1.00224 1.00285 FXN NAM NYC
04/02/2017  00:00.2 1.00223 1.00288 FXN
```

All input gratefully received :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relational databases (RDBMS) aim to store data into related, logical groupings with a system of primary key/foreign keys to normalize storage which among other advantages maintains referential integrity (i.e., no orphaned records) and avoids repetition of stored data. For your situation, consider the following:

1. **DATABASE DESIGN**: Understand the workflow or "story" of your data pieces (e.g., which comes first/after in data entry) and construct the necessary schema of tables. Classic Database 101 example is the Customers-Products-Orders where many customers can purchase multiple products to fill many orders (1-to-many and many-to-many relationships) where primary keys of parent tables are the foreign key of child tables. Hence, aim for a schema layout as below from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17711375/1422451).

   [image: Database Schema]

   For your needs, your schema may involve *Contributors*, *Regions*, *Cities*, *Markets*, *Company (Ticker)*, and *Prices*. This step will make use of DDL commands (`CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE INDEX`, `CREATE SCHEMA`) which can be run in `pyodbc` cursors or `sqlAlchemy` engine calls, sufficing the connected user has such privileges.

   But typically, database design commands are run in a specialized admin console/IDE or command line tools and not application layer code like Python such as SQL Server's Management Studio or sqlcmd; similarly, Oracle's SQL Developer/sqlplus, MySQL's Workbench/cli or PostgreSQL's PgAdmin/psql. Below is example of setup for *Prices* table:

   ```
   # INITIALIZE SQLALCHEMY ENGINE
   connection_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://{}:{}@{}/{}'\
                        .format(db_user,db_password,db_server,db_database)
   engine = create_engine(connection_string)

   sql = """
       CREATE TABLE Prices (
           ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
           DateTime         DATETIME,
           BidPrice         DOUBLE(10,4),
           AskPrice         DOUBLE(10,4),
           ContributorID    INT,  
           RegionID         INT,
           CityID           INT,
           CONSTRAINT FK_Contributor FOREIGN KEY (ContributorID) REFERENCES Contributors (ID),
           CONSTRAINT FK_Region FOREIGN KEY (RegionID) REFERENCES Regions (ID),
           CONSTRAINT FK_City FOREIGN KEY (CityID) REFERENCES Cities (ID)
       )
    """

   # SQL ACTION QUERY VIA TRANSACTION
   with engine.begin() as conn:     
       conn.execute(sql)
   ```
2. **DATA POPULATION**: Because a dataset/dataframe, csv, or spreadsheet are NOT equivalent to a normalized RDBMS table but are actually queries of multiple tables, migration of these sources will require some SQL wrangling to align to your above schema. Simple upload of dataframes into SQL Server tables will lead to inefficient and repetitive storage. Therefore, consider below steps:

   - Staging Tables *(using `to_sql`)*

     Use staging, temp tables which would be raw dumps from pandas. And for NAs issue, use [DataFrame or Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) forward fill , `ffill`, for populating NAs from above rows.

     ```
     # FILL IN NAs IN ALL COLUMNS FROM PREVIOUS ROW
     df = df.ffill()   # OR df.fillna(method='ffill')

     # FILL IN NAs FOR SPECIFIC COLUMNS
     df['Region'] = df['Region'].ffill()
     df['City'] = df['City'].ffill()

     # DUMP DATA INTO DATA FRAME
     df.to_sql(name='pandas_prices_dump', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
     ```
   - Migration to Final Tables *(joining lookup tables by string names)*

     Then, run action queries (i.e., DML commands: `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) for populating final tables from staging, temp tables.

     ```
     sql = """
           INSERT INTO Prices (Datetime, BidPrice, AskPrice,  
                               ContributorID, RegionID, CityID)
           SELECT pd.Datetime, pd.BidPrice, pd.AskPrice, c.ID, r.ID, cy.ID
           FROM pandas_prices_dump pd
           INNER JOIN Contributors c 
                 ON c.ContributorName = pd.Contributor
           INNER JOIN Regions r 
                 ON r.RegionName = pd.Region
           INNER JOIN Cities cy 
                 ON cy.CityName = pd.City
     """

     # APPEND FINAL DATA
     with engine.begin() as conn:     
         conn.execute(sql)

     # DROP STAGING TABLE
     with engine.begin() as conn:     
         conn.execute("DROP TABLE pandas_prices_dump")
     ```
   - Test/Check Final Tables *(using `read_sql`, joining lookup tables by IDs)*

     ```
     # IMPORT INTO PANDAS (EQUIVALENT TO ORIGINAL df)
     sql = """
           SELECT p.Datetime, p.BidPrice, p.AskPrice, 
                  c.ContributorName As Contributor, r.RegionName As Region,
                  cy.CityName As City
           FROM Prices p
           INNER JOIN Contributors c 
                 ON c.ID = pd.ContributorID
           INNER JOIN Regions r 
                 ON r.ID = pd.RegionID
           INNER JOIN Cities cy 
                 ON cy.ID = pd.CityID
     """

     prices_data = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
     ```

Comment: That is already more than I had hoped for and, in addition to my gratitude, my compliments on a very well-structured answer that addressed both principles and specifics. It is a great answer, and the only reason I haven't accepted it immediately is to see whether it's so good no one believes they could better it, or so good it's provocative and someone wants to see whether they can do as well or better! Either way, Kudos!

Comment: Glad to help. Indeed, this is more a *process* question than a *programming* one. Also, your question was a bit open-ended and broad, so others may have read a bit and continued on. Let's hope future readers gain from this post. Happy coding!